# "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used" after unit test

Tags: .net, unit-testing, com

I know - there are quite a few other questions with this title.  I am getting this error after one of my unit tests completes (successfully).  However, I am **not** using any COM objects; I am not calling any unmanaged code in my unit test.  This is the stack trace:

```
   at System.Windows.Input.TextServicesContext.StopTransitoryExtension()
   at System.Windows.Input.TextServicesContext.Uninitialize(Boolean appDomainShutdown)
   at System.Windows.Input.TextServicesContext.TextServicesContextShutDownListener.OnShutDown(Object target, Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.ShutDownListener.HandleShutDown(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [COM exceptions on exit with WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232867/com-exceptions-on-exit-with-wpf)